# Apache Beam cant read Avro file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, avro, apache-beam

I need to read in an avro file from local or gcs, via java.
I followed the example from docs from https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html

```java
Pipeline p = ...;

// A Read from a GCS file (runs locally and using remote execution):
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("schema.avsc"));
PCollection<GenericRecord> records =
    p.apply(AvroIO.readGenericRecords(schema)
            .from("gs://my_bucket/path/to/records-*.avro"));
```

But when I try to process it through a DoFn there doesnt appear to be any data there. 
The avro file does have data and was able to run a function to generate a schema from it. 
If anybody has advice please share.

Comment: Are there any relevant log messages? Can you describe what the `DoFn` is doing? Can you post any more relevant code? Maybe post the full pipeline implementation. In the Dataflow UI, do you see the input element count remain at zero?

Answer (score 2):

I absolutely agree with Andrew, more information would be required. However, I think you should consider using AvroIO.Read which is a more appropriate transform to read records from one or more Avro files.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/avro-io#reading-with-avroio

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("schema.avsc"));

PCollection<GenericRecord> records =
p.apply(AvroIO.Read.named("ReadFromAvro")
                   .from("gs://my_bucket/path/records-*.avro")
                   .withSchema(schema));
```

Comment: I agree however you probably should include a link to the latest Beam documention as the Google stuff is out of date.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for looking into this. I can't share any code because they belong to clients. I did not receive any error messages, and the debugger did see data, but we were not able to see the data in the avro file (via pardo).

I did manage to fix the issue by recreating the dataflow project using the Eclipse wizard. I even used the same code. I wonder why I did not receive any error messages.